# Jquery : Append jquery variable to a class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code

```
   $( ".attachPo" ).click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'))   // prints 59
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $( '#attachPoForm_"+id+"').show();  // id name = attachPoForm_59
    });
```

but which does not work for me , what is the correct vay of appending jQuesy variable to a class or id name

Comment: `$('#attachPoForm_'+id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quotes aren't quite right. Change to:

```
$( '#attachPoForm_'+id).show();
```

This isn't a "jQuery variable", it's just simple Javascript variable and string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is looking for an element with an id of (literally) `#attachPoForm_"+id+"`, I think you mean:

```
$( '#attachPoForm_'+id).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$( ".attachPo" ).click(function() {
    var id = this.id
    $( '#attachPoForm_'+id).show();  // id name = attachPoForm_59
    //                ^^^^ Fixed the quotes here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( ".attachPo" ).click(function() {
       $( '#attachPoForm_'+ $(this).attr('id')).show();  //set  id name = attachPoForm_59
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A mistake at

```
    $( '#attachPoForm_"+id+"').show();  // id name = attachPoForm_59
```

should be

```
    $( '#attachPoForm_'+id+'').show();  // id name = attachPoForm_59
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **this.id** like,

```
$( ".attachPo" ).click(function() {
    var id=this.id;
    alert(id);
    $("#attachPoForm_"+id).show();  // id name = attachPoForm_59
});
```